# How to select tasks where userName is "xx"

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I have 2 tables (Task table and user table)
task table have list of users 
how to select tasks where userName is "xx"
using criteria in nhibernate 2

Answer (score 1):

```
    var tasks = _session.QueryOver<Task>()
            .Fetch(x => x.User).Eager
            .Where(x => x.User.Username == "xx")
            .List();
```

or

```
        User userAlias = null;
        var tasks = _session.QueryOver<Task>()
            .JoinAlias(x => x.User, () => userAlias, JoinType.InnerJoin)
            .Where(x=>userAlias.UserName=="xx")
            .List();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i work with nhibernate 2 (QueryOver not exist in it)